# Electron will-download keeps getting interrupted

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to download a file, but it keeps getting interrupted, and I have no idea why. I can not find any information on how to debug the reason it got interrupted either.

Here is where I am saving the file:

> C:\Users\rnaddy\AppData\Roaming\Tachyon\games\murware\super-chain-reaction\web.zip

```
window.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
    let path = url.parse(item.getURL()).pathname;
    let dev = path.split('/')[3] || null;
    let game = path.split('/')[4] || null;
    if (!dev && !game) {
        item.cancel();
    } else {
        item.setSavePath(Settings.fileDownloadLocation(dev, game, 'web'));
        item.on('updated', (event, state) => {
            let progress = 0;
            if (state == 'interrupted') {
                console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed');
            } else if (state == 'progressing') {
                progress = item.getReceivedBytes() / item.getTotalBytes();
                if (item.isPaused()) {
                    console.log('Download is paused');
                } else {
                    console.log(`Received bytes: ${item.getReceivedBytes()}; Progress: ${progress.toFixed(2)}%`);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my listener that will trigger the above:

```
ipcMain.on(name, (evt) => {
    window.webContents.downloadURL('http://api.gamesmart.com/v2/download/murware/super-chain-reaction');
});
```

Here is the output that I am getting in my console:

```
Received bytes: 0; Progress: 0.00%
Received bytes: 233183; Progress: 0.02%
Download is interrupted but can be resumed
```

I have a host file setup:

```
127.0.0.1 api.gamesmart.com
```

When I try to access the path http://api.gamesmart.com/v2/download/murware/super-chain-reaction in chrome, the file downloads just fine into my Downloads folder. So, what is causing this?

Answer (score 3):

If you set the specific directory for downloading, you should use full file path with the file name in `item.setSavePath()` method. The best way to do it, fetching the file name from `downloaditem` object (`item` in your case) itself. You can use `item.getFilename()` to get the name of the current download item easily. [here is the doc](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/download-item/#downloaditemgetfilename)

And also there is a good way to get frequently used public system directory paths in electron. That is, using `app.getPath(name)` method. `name` would be the pre-defined String by electron for several directories. [here is the doc](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname)

So, your complete setSavePath function would be,`app.getPath("downloads") + "/" + item.getFilename()`

In your case, if you are OK with your file path extraction method, only thing you are missing is filename at the end of the download path.

Of course you can use any other string as the file name if you wish. But remember to put correct extension though. :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the correct Windows path separator (`\`), .e.g. `'directory\\file.zip'`. Generally, Node.js uses `/` for any platform, but this seems to be sensitive about the path separator.

Comment: You can import the node `path` module and use `path.sep` to use the "correct" one for your OS:


`const path = require('path');
let slash = path.sep;
let file = __dirname + slash + "file.zip";`